# load .htaccess dynamically depending on the subdomain on multiple domain based web app

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Within my custom built PHP web applicaion I have multiple domains pointing to the `/root/abc` folder. `IE: domain.com; mobile.domain.com, admin.domain.com` and so on.

The way my CMS is setup the `index.php` file in `/root/abc` loads different `index.php` files that are stored on sub directories like `/root/abc/mobile`, `/root/abc/admin`, etc.. depending on the subdomain names.

I am having different `.htacess` files at `/root/abc`, `/root/abc/mobile` and `/root/abc/admin` respective to sub domains.

At this point I want to cache files from domain.com and mobile.domain.com but the cache should not work for admin.domain.com, and other `subdomain.domain.com`

Firstly, `.htaccess` file on `/root/abc` loads and then `index.php` file on `/root/abc` loads too. This loaded `index.php` on root loads different folders varying on the sub domain and other properites respective to `subdomain.domain.com`. The sub domain name is dynamic meaning the subdomain names and folder directories changes.

1.. Even if I use HTML meta tags to clear cache it does not work. Can you explain this behavior?

2.. How to load .htaccess files dynamically depending on the subdomain name?

Comment: Here's a question about HTML meta tags and caching control, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1341089/1741542

Comment: Thank you Olaf, That was helpful for Meta Tags, the bad thing is it is not working on older IE version.

Comment: How to load .htaccess files dynamically depending on the subdomain name using .htaccess itslef?

Comment: .htaccess files are loaded unconditionally, based on the appropriate directory alone. If you want configuration based on the domain, you must do so with `If`, `RewriteCond`, or - better yet - with a virtual host configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

An `.htaccess` file applies to the directory it is in an all its subdirectories. Only the filesystem matters for this.

> Even if I use HTML meta tags to clear cache it does not work.

Meta tags for cache control are [a joke](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META) and real HTTP headers trump them anyway.

---

Avoid `.htaccess`:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

— [The Apache HTTPD manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

You have your subdomains set up in the Apache configuration. Set your cache control directives there, in the `<VirtualHost>` blocks instead.

Comment: That was quick and this helped me to understand about HTTPD. After reading your answer I went through Godaddy and I found out that I do not have access to edit the same. Is there any way to do the same with .htaccess inherting .htaccess depending on the directories